# verify digital signature using public key in openssl

Tags: c++, cryptography, openssl, digital-signature, cryptoapi

I have signed a data in windows using wincrypt cryptoapi (PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING) and in linux, I have x509 certificate and the signed message which i have to verify

```
Code in windows to sign :
hStoreHandle = CertOpenStore(
    CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,
    0,
    NULL,
    CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER,
    CERT_PERSONAL_STORE_NAME
);
CheckError((BOOL)hStoreHandle, L"CertOpenStore....................... ");

// Get signer's certificate with access to private key.
do {
    // Get a certificate that matches the search criteria
    pSignerCert = CertFindCertificateInStore(
        hStoreHandle,
        MY_TYPE,
        0,
        CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR,
        SignerName,
        pSignerCert
    );
    CheckError((BOOL)pSignerCert, L"CertFindCertificateInStore.......... ");

    // Get the CSP, and check if we can sign with the private key           
    bResult = CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(
        pSignerCert,
        0,
        NULL,
        &hCryptProv,
        &dwKeySpec,
        NULL
    );
    CheckError(bResult, L"CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey... ");

} while ((dwKeySpec & AT_SIGNATURE) != AT_SIGNATURE);

// Create the hash object.
bResult = CryptCreateHash(
    hCryptProv, 
    CALG_MD5, 
    0, 
    0, 
    &hHash
);
CheckError(bResult, L"CryptCreateHash..................... ");

// Open the file with the content to be signed 
hDataFile = CreateFileW(DataFileName,
    GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_READ,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
    NULL
);
CheckError((hDataFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE), L"CreateFile.......................... ");

// Compute the cryptographic hash of the data.
while (bResult = ReadFile(hDataFile, rgbFile, BUFSIZE, &cbRead, NULL))
{
    if (cbRead == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    CheckError(bResult, L"ReadFile............................ ");

    bResult = CryptHashData(
        hHash, 
        rgbFile, 
        cbRead, 
        0
    );
    CheckError(bResult, L"CryptHashData....................... ");

}
CheckError(bResult, L"ReadFile............................ ");

// Sign the hash object
dwSigLen = 0;
bResult = CryptSignHash(
    hHash, 
    AT_SIGNATURE, 
    NULL, 
    0, 
    NULL, 
    &dwSigLen
);
CheckError(bResult, L"CryptSignHash....................... ");

pbSignature = (BYTE *)malloc(dwSigLen);
CheckError((BOOL)pbSignature, L"malloc.............................. ");

bResult = CryptSignHash(
    hHash, 
    AT_SIGNATURE, 
    NULL, 
    0, 
    pbSignature, 
    &dwSigLen
);
CheckError(bResult, L"CryptSignHash....................... ");

// Create a file to save the signature
hSignatureFile = CreateFileW(
    SignatureFileName,
    GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    NULL,
    CREATE_ALWAYS,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL
);
CheckError((hSignatureFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE), L"CreateFile.......................... ");

// Write the signature to the file
bResult = WriteFile(
    hSignatureFile, 
    (LPCVOID)pbSignature, 
    dwSigLen, 
    &lpNumberOfBytesWritten, 
    NULL
);
CheckError(bResult, L"WriteFile........................... ");



In openssl i tried:

 openssl rsautl -verify -inkey pubkey.pem -keyform PEM -pubin -in signedmessage   

it is throwing error::   
RSA operation error  
4296:error:0406706C:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT:data greater than modlen:fips_rsa_eay.c:709:  
and this error if the signedmessage is hashed
RSA operation error
4432:error:0407006A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:block type is not     01:rsa_pk1.c:100:
4432:error:04067072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT:padding check     failed:fips_rsa_eay.c:748:


i also tried :  
   openssl dgst -verify pubkey.pem -signature signedmessage
but program goes into infinite loop

I also find one command:
 int PKCS7_verify(PKCS7 *p7, STACK_OF(X509) *certs, X509_STORE *store, BIO *indata, BIO *out, int flags);
     but it require too many argument of which i am not aware of.e.g there is no x509_store, crlfile used in this
```

. can any one tell me **how to verify the signed message**

**I get x509 pem certificate and signedmessage as input in linux which i have to verify**

Comment: It's possibly a format mismatch. What is the output of your windows function and the key you use to verify? Maybe include links, hexdumps or some such?

Comment: i have attached the code used to sign

Comment: What is an example of a signed data and the pem public key?

Comment: The big Integers (like `n` and `d`) are probably in little-endian format. I believe `e` is a DWORD and is OK. I also believe WinCrypt also uses little-endian for the signature because of [`CryptDecodeObjectEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptdecodeobjectex) and `CRYPT_DECODE_NO_SIGNATURE_BYTE_REVERSAL_FLAG`. You should reverse the byte order to big-endian so OpenSSL can use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some example by mail, we got to the following recipe

setup:
we have a x509 certificate cert.p7b to start with, a file message.txt, a Windows produced signed.dat, and using sha1 for definiteness.

`openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -outform PEM -in cert.p7b -out cert.pem -print_certs`

`openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -pubkey > pubkey.pem`

(this need only be done once for a certificate, to get a public key in PEM format)
then reverse `signed.dat` bytewise to `signed.dat.rev`
(using a simple C program, or output the bytes differently on Windows, in alternative form) 
and finally

`openssl dgst -sha1 -verify pubkey.pem -signature signed.dat.rev message.txt`

The main problem was the reverse byte order on Windows (which I have seen before)

Comment: I have tried : openssl rsautl -verify -in signed_HashSign -pubin -inkey pub.pem -pkcs -asn1parse -hexdump   and that gives:: RSA operation error
4676:error:0407006A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:block type is not 01:rsa_pk1.c:100:
4676:error:04067072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_DECRYPT:padding check failed:fips_rsa_eay.c:748:

Comment: adding -rev might help too, as CryptoAPI reverses the order of buffers in some cases.

Comment: `openssl pkeyutl -in file -verify -sigfile signed_hash -pubin -inkey key.pem -keyform PEM -rsa_padding_mode:pkcs1` might work, maybe with `-rev` added. It's hard to try this without concrete example data!

Comment: @henno my openssl is OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
and there is no -pkeyutl and -rev option :(

Comment: Mine is 1.0.0, so that explains it... What are your examples ?

Comment: examples? did u mean option provided by openssl

Comment: i will try on 1.0.0. then will let u know if any prob arise .. thanks

Comment: no examples of your pem public key file and a file and its signature.

Comment: `openssl pkeyutl -verify -in file_to_sign -sigfile sig -pubin -inkey mypubkey.pem -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:pkcs1` does give "Signature Verified Successfully". The signature is made with `openssl pkeyutl -in file_to_sign -out sig -sign -inkey mykey.pem -rsa_padding_mode:pkcs1` where mypubkey.pem is the public key and mykey.pem the private key. `openssl rsautl -sign -in file_to_sign -out sig2 -inkey mykey.pem -pkcs` has the same result (sig2 = sig).

Comment: -pkeyutl is no option, but a command (like enc), so like I typed openssl pkeyutl and then options follow. Just a remark.

Comment: @Henno thanks for this info.. problem is i have signed the message in windows using cryptoapi (PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING) sai mentionedd above and verifying it in linux using ur command it is giving verification failure.. I think there is sm padding issue in win crypto api and linux openssl..

Comment: Yep, like I suggested in the first reply. Also, -verify checks the file contents directly, so we need to put the digest in the file first, and then verify that. But again, include an example! So we can see the formats, etc.

Comment: what kind of example? i am not able to get this.. u want signed message? hexdump?

Comment: signed message (in hex) and pubkey.pem, plus the file you sign. Then I can try to verify it using openssl stuff.

Comment: ok but how to upload that ?  can you tell me you email id? thanks

Comment: A dropbox folder? or try my first name, second name (all one word, lowercase) at gmail etc.

Comment: The ASN1 might be the problem, it's not exactly PEM. But I'll wait for an example.